# Выравнивание стрелки

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Есть код

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        all__buttons=document.querySelectorAll('.header__button');
        
            [].forEach.call(all__buttons, function(selected__button){
                selected__button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    event.target.style.backgroundColor='#5f3ec0';
                    event.target.style.color='#ffffff';
                
                });
            }); 
        */
    
        $('.header__button').click(function(event){
                $('.header__button').removeClass('lilac');
                $(this).addClass('lilac');
                event.target.style.color='#ffffff';
        }
        );
    
    
const getItem = `<div class="cardexample">
                            <div class="mobileimage">
                                    <img class="mobiles" src="../img/mobileimage.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content__title">
                                Iphone 11, почему такой же как и Pro Max, может быть большим в 3 строки вот так
                            </div>
                            <div class="video__icon">
                                <span>
                                    <button class="crashvideo">Краш видео</button>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <a href="#"><img class="youtube__icon-play" src="../img/Vector.png"></a>
                                </span> 
                                <span>
                                    <button class="crashvideo" id="ex2">Краш видео</button>
                                </span>                         
                            </div>
                            <div class="content__text">
                                Видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые вопросы может быть большим в 3 строки, видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые
                            </div>
                            <div class="endlink">
                                <a href="#">Читать далее</a>
                            </div>              
                        </div>
                        `;

            const getAllItems = () => {
                let content = '';
                
                for (let i=0; i<4; i++) {
                    content+=getItem;
                }
                return content;
            }       

            const renderAllItems = () => {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=getAllItems();
            }

            renderAllItems();                           
    
    
    }
    
    
    )
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    /*height: 100%;*/
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: 93px;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #5f3ec0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
}

.cardexample {
    width: 100%;
}

.mobileimage img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.mobiles {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content__title {
    font-family: TTNorms-Medium;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21.6px;
    
    margin: 0.3% 15px 0 15px;
}

.crashvideo {
    width: 115px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    
    background-color: #5f3ec0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.video__icon {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

#ex2 {
    display: none;
}

.youtube__icon-play {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    margin-top: 20.5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 18.75px;
    
    align: center;
}

.content__text {
    margin-top: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    
    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* or 22px */


    /* Main text */

    color: #cacaca;
}

.endlink {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #121212;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.endlink a {
    color: #121212;
}

.endlink a:visited {
    color: #800080;
}

.big__button {
    width: 100%;
}

.show__more {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    
    margin: 30px auto;
    
    background-color: #5f3ec0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #303030;
}

.contacts {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.contacts__title {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    
    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.contacts__telephones {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 15px;

    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.telephone1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.telephone2 {
    
}

.requestcall {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 165px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #303030;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.internetshop {
        margin-top: 0;
        
}

.internetshop__title {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.disclosure__arrow {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-top: 30.62px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.lilac {
    background-color: #5f3ec0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer">
                <div class="contacts">
                    <div class="contacts__title">
                        Контакты
                    </div>
                    <div class="contacts__telephones">
                        <div class="telephone1">
                        +7 (800) 333 32 24
                        </div>
                        <div class="telephone2">
                        +7 (812) 448 68 11
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="requestcall">
                        Заказать звонок
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="internetshop">
                        <div class="internetshop__title">
                            Интернет магазин
                        </div>
                        <div class="disclosure__arrow">
                            >
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="company">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="help__to__the__buyer">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="socialnetworks__links">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="allrights">
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Он отображается как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а необходимо как на https://www.figma.com/file/noqP1gzhrAlGAErPNBgknp/test?node-id=1%3A1345. Подскажите как выровнять стрелку >, повернутую на 90 градусов. Она должна быть на уровне текста Интернет магазин, а не после второго телефона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот так, например. Вы должны задавать явную высоту, когда пытаетесь что-то поварачивать через `rotate`, иначе контент может занимать 100% ширины, а при развороте на 90 градусов он становится высотой, и происходит непонятно что...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.header>.header__text {
  position: relative;
  width: 93px;
  height: 24px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 129px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* identical to box height, or 24px */
  color: #000000;
}


/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/

.header__button {
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-color: #5f3ec0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 1.75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.cardexample {
  width: 100%;
}

.mobileimage img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.mobiles {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content__title {
  font-family: TTNorms-Medium;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21.6px;
  margin: 0.3% 15px 0 15px;
}

.crashvideo {
  width: 115px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: #5f3ec0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.video__icon {
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#ex2 {
  display: none;
}

.youtube__icon-play {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20.5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 18.75px;
  align: center;
}

.content__text {
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  /* or 22px */
  /* Main text */
  color: #cacaca;
}

.endlink {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #121212;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.endlink a {
  color: #121212;
}

.endlink a:visited {
  color: #800080;
}

.big__button {
  width: 100%;
}

.show__more {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #5f3ec0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #303030;
}

.contacts {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.contacts__title {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.contacts__telephones {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: TT Norms;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.telephone1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.telephone2 {}

.requestcall {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 165px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #303030;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.internetshop {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.internetshop__title {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.disclosure__arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.lilac {
  background-color: #5f3ec0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contacts__title">
        Контакты
      </div>
      <div class="contacts__telephones">
        <div class="telephone1">
          +7 (800) 333 32 24
        </div>
        <div class="telephone2">
          +7 (812) 448 68 11
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="requestcall">
                        Заказать звонок
                    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="internetshop">
      <div class="internetshop__title">
        Интернет магазин
      </div>
      <div class="disclosure__arrow">
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="company">

    </div>
    <div class="help__to__the__buyer">

    </div>
    <div class="socialnetworks__links">

    </div>
    <div class="allrights">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```